# Why is only upvotes-downvotes visible until high enough rep?

Tags: feature-request

Clearly there is a huge difference between an answer with -1000 downvotes and 1030 upvotes and one with 30 upvotes only. A visitor reading the former answer would be deceived. Why are we hiding the community's judgement of a post? Its like hiding half the answer

Comment: Viewing that information costs a lot of performance. That is why not everyone has the right to execute it.

Comment: You may want to install a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) to get rid of the rep requirement.